# Null value output after clicking submit button

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I expect to receive the value of the button to a.aaa

but i get null instead

a.aaa needs to be "stackOverflow" string in  [HttpPost]

> controller code

```
 public class DefaultController : Controller
        {
            // GET: Default
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }

            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Index(Class1 a)
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

> model

```
namespace WebApplication3.Models
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public string aaa { get; set; }
    }
}
```

> view

```
@model WebApplication3.Models.Class1

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
     <button type="button" name="aaa" id="aaa" value="stackOverflow">pressMe</button>
     <input type="submit" />
}
```

Comment: Your code as posted here is fine (tested it in my project and the value of property `aaa` is `stackOverflow` on postback).

Comment: i change one line i ment to write                                     <button type="button" name="aaa" id="aaa" value="stackOcerflow"></button>

Comment: `button` is not an control that posts back!

Comment: and why i need to do   Request["aaa"] in input type                        this exmple work and the value insert into model without Request["aaa"]                                             <select  id="aaa" name="aaa">
            <option>stack</option>
            <option>overflow</option>         
        </select>

Comment: so how i pass button value and give it a name like button html control, value of input control is also is name

Comment: @david: Why are you trying to pass a button value through your `ActionResult`?

Comment: Its unclear what you are asking. If you want to post a value, use an `<input>` (type = text, hidden, submit, radio etc), a `<select>` or `<textarea>` (as you did before the edit)

Comment: i have 7 buttons and i want to know which buttons was pressed             if someone pressed 2 buttons i change the color of the button          i ask in javascripit which buttons changed there color and i add the text label of the button to his value' i expect to get button label on the server side to know which buttons pressed

Comment: That not what you question says. Edit it with the real code to explain what your trying to achieve. (I suspect its a case of adding a hidden input with `name="aaa"` and updating the value of it using javascript)

Answer (score 0):

What is [HttpPost] ?

You should find the value in `Request["aaa"]`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "DefaultController ", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <p>
        @Html.TextBox("aaa", "stackOverflow")
        <input type="submit" value="Text" />
    </p>
}
```

This code should work for sure, you can try it !

Answer (score 0):

This works correctly for me. Set a breakpoint at the `return View();` line in the `ActionResult Index(Class1 a)` method.

This should demonstrate that `a` contains a value of `stackOverflow` for it's property `aaa`.

If you cannot replicate this behavior, please clarify the behavior that you would expect.

[image: Breakpoint]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend implementing via javascript/ajax

In your html's body

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myJsFunc('aaa');">Press Me</a>
```

In your html's script

```
function myJsFunc(somedata) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: '/DefaultController/Index',
        data: { 'somedata' : somedata },
        success: function(result) {
                     //do something
                 }
        error: function (errorData) {alert(errorData);}
    });
};
```

In your controller

```
[HttpPost]    
public ActionResult Index(string somedata)
{
      if(somedata == "aaa")
      {
            //do something
      }
      return Json("successData");
 }
```

Then style links as buttons with css.

Or replace your buttons with inputs and follow these [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19650345/mvc-razor-form-with-multiple-different-submit-buttons#answers)