# How to call [HttpPost] method of web api in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, http-post

I have one method and i need to call it.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public List<MyClass> GetPanels(SomeModel filter)
    {
    ...
    //doing something with filter...
    ...
    return new List<MyClass>();
    }
```

I need to call this method by httpclient or HttpWebRequest , i mean any way.

Comment: You can use ajax request, You can refer to this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16186083/making-a-simple-ajax-call-to-controller-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/02/16/httpclient-is-here.aspx

Comment: are you facing any issues? you should google first. right?

Comment: Can you show us what did you try ? and what problems did you face ?

Answer (score 2):

Using the `HttpClient` you can do like this:

```
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new SomeModel {Message = "Ping"}));
        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost/yourhost/api/yourcontroller", content);

        var value = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass[]>(value);

        // do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use `WebClient`. Here is the example:

```
        using (var wb = new WebClient())
        {
            var uri = new Uri("http://yourhost/api/GetPanels");
            // Your headers, off course if you need it
            wb.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "whatEver=5");
            // data - data you need to pass in POST request
            var response = wb.UploadValues(uri, "POST", data);
        }
```

**ADDED**
To convert your data to nameValue collection you can use next:

```
NameValueCollection formFields = new NameValueCollection();

data.GetType().GetProperties()
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(pi => formFields.Add(pi.Name, pi.GetValue(data, null).ToString()));
```

Then just use the `formFields` in POST request.

Comment: In the place of data it requires NameValueCollection. When i use my object directly it gives error:-

'Argument 3: cannot convert from 'SomeModel' to 'System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection''

Comment: There is a 100 ways how to convert instance of a class to NameValueCollection, I have added one of them to my answer.