# How to pass model from seperate MVC Project to External Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this Method within my Web API Project

```
 public UserProfile CheckCredentials([FromBody] UserLogin userLogin)
 {
        UserProfile userProfile;

        userLogin.Password = Crypto.Encrypt(userLogin.Password);

        return userProfile;
 }
```

In my seperate MVC Project I need to call this method and pass in the UserLogin model which is populated from the view inside my MVC Project.

I know how to do this in javascript as shown here (example)

```
var apiurl = "http://localhost:50793/api/ImageUpload/UploadImage"

var customer = { customer_name: "Scott", company_name: "HP" };
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(customer),
    url: apiurl,
    contentType: "application/json"
});
```

Which calls this web api

```
 [HttpPost]
public void UploadImage([FromBody] Customer customer)
{
    string name = customer.company_name;

    string dooda = string.Empty;
}
```

But I'm uncertain on how to do this/syntax in MVC I have googled for a solution with no avail, Can someone show me a solution on how to do this.

Thanks

** Update **
I have installed RestSharp, and I now have the following code

```
   var url = "http://localhost:28247/api/UserLoginApi/CheckCredentials";

            var client = new RestClient();
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST) { Resource = url, RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json };

            request.AddBody(userLogin);

            var response = (RestResponse)client.Execute(request);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

It returns with the error 
    Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: uri"

*** My Controller ***

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(UserLogin userLogin)
    {

      // Call Web Api here and pass in userLogin

       return View(userLogin);

     }
```

Turns out the code I showed above I.e the rest client I can't use as that is for post get put and delete methods and as my api controller has a variety and multiple post methods that wouldn't be suitable so I have to ask the question how do I call the above api check credentials passing in the login model

Comment: Can you post your `Customer` model?

Comment: @mattytommo that is an example, it's what I used earlier doing this via ajax, now I want to learn how to do it in c#

Comment: So the Web API is a separate project? In which case - to call it in c# you'd just construct a [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @jamess I looked at that, but I'm unsure how to pass the model userLogin to the web api

Comment: @ScottAtkinson - look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18064141/2463120

Comment: You can look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27560933/how-to-call-httppost-method-of-web-api-in-c-sharp/27561408#27561408

Comment: @peco I like your solution, but I get an error message under await which is "the await operator can only be used in a method or a lambda marked with async modified" also where do I specify the name of the method I want to call I can see from your example you specify the controller, but not the method name

Comment: @peco ok I managed to get it to work, but if I'm returning a model to my controller from the web api how am I suppose to pass that back because the example you have given is of async task and I need the values inside the data variable

Comment: @ScottAtkinson you need to mark your method as `async` and then wrap your return value in a `Task` when using the `await` keyword. So your action would look like this: `public async Task<ActionResult> Login(UserLogin userLogin)`. Does this work?