# Ajax URL - Incorrect .net #c

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax

Been following some tutorials, as i'm learning C#, however was just attempting to make an ajax call to the server, i'm using my localhost.

As far as I can tell i'm doing its right, but it's obviously not.
Maybe it my folder structure or just the name of the file.

[image: Folder Structure]

The Default.aspx file is at the project root
Here is my ajax call

```
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "Default.aspx",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "{'FirstName':'test','LastName':'test1','City':'test3','EmailID':'test4'}",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("Woo!");
        },
        error: function (result) {
            console.log("fail!");
        }
    });
```

I know eventually it will have to call a method within the file, but its not even finding it at the moment.

Thanks in advance, James

Comment: you is trying to call a webmethod?

Answer (score 0):

You can use controller Home and create the one action.

Example:

```
public ActionResult FirstAjax()
{
    return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

After that your jquery ajax is:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "Home/FirstAjax",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("Woo!");
        },
        error: function (result) {
            console.log("fail!");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Would that go in the Default.aspx file?

Comment: this way does not, the development of the method is done in the controller.

Comment: So i can can just create a new controller, called 'Home'?

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information on the set up of this, or direct me somewhere with a clear example?

Comment: folow this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16186083/making-a-simple-ajax-call-to-controller-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Still no luck, just want to make a simple ajax call

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28253608/jquery-click-method-is-not-attached-to-button/28253657#28253657