# jquery click method is not attached to button

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have asp.net mvc 5 application but I can't get this fairly simple script to work. I am new to this MVC (I am WebForms guy). 
Basically jQuery is not attaching .click() event to the button to post data to the underlying controller.

Can somebody pinpoint what I am doing wrong?

The View (HelloWorld/Index.cshtml):

```
@model HelloWorld.Models.HelloWorldModel

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Welcome","HelloWorld",FormMethod.Post, new {id = "myhelloform"})){

    <span>Name:</span> 
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model=> model.Name)
    <button id="btnPost" type="button">Post</button>
    }
    </div>

    <script>
    var testform = function () {
        var init = function () {
            $("#btnPost").on("click", function () {
                alert("anybody there??");
                submitForm();
            });
        };

        var submitForm = function () {
            $.hit({
                url: "@Url.Action("Welcome", "HelloWorld")",
                data: $("#myhelloform").serializeArray(),
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response.Message);
                }
            });
        };

        return {
            Init: init
        };
    };

    </script>
</body>
</html>
</html>
```

The Controller (Controllers/HelloWorldController.cs):

```c#
using System.Web.Mvc;
namespace HelloWorld.Controllers
{
    public class HelloWorldController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Welcome()
        {
            return Json("test");
        }
    }
}
```

The Model (Models/HelloWorldModel.cs)

```
namespace HelloWorld.Models
{
    public class HelloWorldModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like your init function is never being called... Add an alert to the top of that function to check.

Comment: Tried that... no alert is being hit :(

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HCdFXM Works without testform and init

Comment: @JAT - that seems to work, thanks - i.e. getting rid of testform and init. Please post as answer. Next problem occurs now 
`submitForm()` is invoke but nothing happens, i.e. `alert(response.Message)` never fires?

Comment: Done, please ask the next problem in a separate question

Comment: Only question allowed for me every 90 minutes - I guess I speak too much :p

Comment: Follow up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28254756/parsing-jquery-response-success-is-never-hit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the variables testform and init and it works (Also need to use $( document ).ready as @Tbseven mentions):

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
                $("#btnPost").on("click", function () 
                                 {
                                    alert("anybody there??");

                                 });
});
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HCdFXM

Answer (score 1):

You have to place your jquery code inside next function:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Here
});
```

Comment: Even that does not work. Same problem in both IE 11 and FF 35.

Answer (score 1):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $("#btnPost").on("click", function () {
       alert("anybody there??");
       submitForm();
   });

   function submitForm () {
         $.hit({
             url: "@Url.Action("Welcome", "HelloWorld")",
             data: $("#myhelloform").serializeArray(),
             success: function (response) {
                 alert(response.Message);
             });
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks @JeffWatkins - JAT beat you to it though, so I awarded the answer to him.

Comment: No problem, I'm just here to help (and to keep my eye in, as I rarely get chance to code nowadays).

Answer (score 1):

You can use **input** instead of **button** and there is no need to add click event for that.

```
<input type="submit" id="btnPost" />
```

Comment: I could but basically I simplified my question here on SO - the reason for using <button> in this case is because of some css rules related to only <button>.

Comment: I agree, you should catch submit event +1

Comment: @Sha: you can add that too for that via applying this simple rule: `input[type="submit"] { //your rule here.. }`

Comment: Yes but in this project it would require a lot of work to switch from button to input... but thanks anyways.