# javascript or ajax to update database with asp.net mvc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a function here from a change event on a dropdownlist. When the selection gets changed I want to update a row in my database. Should I use javascript or ajax. I don't want the page to be refreshed. I think it should be ajax, but not sure? If ajax, can anyone point me to a tutorial/video/etc?

Here is where I want to update my db row.

```
var statusdropdown = document.getElementById("enumstatus");
statusdropdown.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
    // call db and update row
}, false);
```

Comment: javascript or ajax? ...you realize ajax means asynchronous javascript(and xml)...right?  You definitely want ajax.

Comment: not too familiar with asp.net...you basically want to pass the current value of #enumstatus to the function that updates the db.

Comment: do you have a function that you've written to update the db yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you using asp.net mvc.

You can write your ajax calls with pure javascript [Ajax docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX) or the easiest way, using [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

You need to add one action on your controller to receive the ajax data, and then insert/update your db.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16186083/making-a-simple-ajax-call-to-controller-in-asp-net-mvc), [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381533(v=vs.100).aspx) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B59skvlroyc).

Answer (score 0):

Most common scenario would be making an ajax call using HTTP POST/PUT to a controller method, which would then handle the data and update the database directly or pass through to your service/data layer code.

Probably the easiest way to make the call would be using the jQuery.ajax method. Documentation can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
            var name = $('#TextBox1').val();
            var email = $('#TextBox2').val();
            if (name != '' && email != '') {
                $.ajax
                    ({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'Home/UpdateDB',     //if it is plain asp.net then UpdateDB is declared as WebMethod 
                        async: false,
                        data: "{'name':'" + name + "','email':'" + email + "'}",
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset =utf-8',
                        success: function (data) {
                            var obj = data.d;
                            if (obj == 'true') {
                                $('#TextBox1').val('');
                                $('#TextBox2').val('');
                                alert("Data Saved Successfully");
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                            alert("Error Occured, Try Again");
                        }
                    });
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> - fg
> - iuou
> - uouienter link description here
> - uiouidfgs*dfgd*dfgdfgdfgdgdgd##

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

Heading

---

##*

> - uio
> - uiopomkl
> - hjlkdsg
> - dsf
> - dfgdg
>
> Blockquote

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).