# How to add button and redirect to another view in MVC4?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have one doubt.

I have one view called `CustomerMaster`.  In `CustomerMaster` view I have field Like 'Area', 'City' etc. If city is already in the list it will be automatically shown in the Dropdown .

Suppose the City which I need is not in the list, means I have to add that city. So I decided to keep one 'Add' button near to 'city' field. If I click that button it needs to redirect to that view. So how can i do this in MVC4?

1) How can I keep button near to the field?
2) How to redirect from one view to another view while clicking the button in mvc4?

Thanks .

Comment: next time ask google first

Comment: Sneha, I don't think questions like this will be encouraged in SO. Please do a research by yourself before posting a question. Try to do by yourself and raise questions if you stuck with some issues.

Comment: I am a fresher and very very new to mvc so only i stuck with this simple concept. How could you say like this. what freshers can do think about that?

Answer (score 1):

answer of question 1 is "using HTML"
answer of question 2 is "using Html.ActionLink()" method

Comment: I know button coding to keep button .. but i donno how to redirect to another view . In need that "using Html.ActionLink()" coding

Answer (score 0):

Make an ajax call from the view CustomerMaster on click of button. The syntax would be like

```
 $.ajax({
url : updatecontroller
success: dosomething
});
```

In the updatecontroller return the corresponding view which is one more html page.

I have given you the idea, for the exact syntax of making an ajax on button click here is the link 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41828/JQuery-AJAX-with-ASP-NET-MVC.

Comment: Additionally check this link: This looks pretty simple follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16186083/making-a-simple-ajax-call-to-controller-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: ok Dudes . lets i have a try . If i get any error means i will post my question again..