# How to get all value of all checked rows in table with FormCollection?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have searched for help but can find any topic that could help me.
I have a table like this

```
<table id="tableftest" class="table table-striped table-vmiddle">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th data-column-id="" data-sortable="false">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="checkall" title="chọn tất cả" onclick="" />
                    </th>
                    <th data-column-id="ip">IP</th>
                    <th data-column-id="network" hidden="hidden">Network</th>
                    <th data-column-id="sender">GateWay</th>
                    <th data-column-id="received">SubnetMask</th>
                    <th data-column-id="viewdetail">VPS được gán</th>
                    @*<th data-column-id="commands" data-formatter="commands" data-sortable="false"></th>*@
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (VPSIP ipitem in ip)
                {
                    <tr>
                        @if (ipitem.VPSID != null)
                        {
                            <td></td>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <td>
                                <input type="checkbox" class="ipDelListClass" name="ipDelList" value="@ipitem.IpID" />
                            </td>
                        }

                        <td>@(ipitem.IPAddress)</td>
                        <td hidden="hidden">@ipitem.NetworkRanx.NetworkAddress</td>
                        <td>@(ipitem.NetworkRanx.Gateway)</td>
                        <td>@ipitem.NetworkRanx.SubnetMask</td>
                        @if (ipitem.VPSID != null)
                        {
                            <td><a href="@Url.Action("VPSDetail", "TechnicalStaff", new {ipitem.VPSID })">@(ipitem.VPSs.VPSName)</a></td>
                            @*<td></td>*@
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <td></td>
                            @*<td>
                                <button title="Xóa ip" class="btn btn-danger zmdi zmdi-delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#IpDel_@ipitem.IpID" style="font-size:medium"></button>
                            </td>*@
                        }
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

When I check all checkboxs in table and click button delete, it will post data to this controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult IPDeleteMany(FormCollection f)
    {
        var ipDelArray = f.Get("ipDelList");
        ServerBusiness serBu = new ServerBusiness();
        string[] ipDelList = ipDelArray.Split(',');
        try
        {
            foreach (string ipId in ipDelList)
            {
                var iprow = serBu.getIPById(int.Parse(ipId));
                serBu.removeIPById(iprow);
            }
            TempData["Success"] = "IP đã bị xóa!";
            return RedirectToAction("ViewListIP", "TechnicalStaff");
        }
        catch
        {
            TempData["Error"] = "Lỗi!";
            return RedirectToAction("ViewListIP", "TechnicalStaff");
        }
    }
```

When it runs, it only get values of rows that is visible, not all the rows in table.

Is there anyway to get all of values checked in table include invisible rows?

Comment: Do you use Ajax or you post back your data to server?

Comment: I use Form to post data to server

Comment: Should I use ajax?

Comment: No , and do you use component for your grid which uses ajax?

Comment: I don't clearly understand your question, but I didn't use ajax for my gridview above.

Comment: `<td hidden="hidden">@ipitem.NetworkRanx.NetworkAddress</td>` this is what you say which doesn't posted back to server? as I see it isn't any row which can be hidden because your rows are visible.

Comment: Not that column, that column I just used to filter but now show in gridview. What i need to get is value of this <td>
                                <input type="checkbox" class="ipDelListClass" name="ipDelList" value="@ipitem.IpID" />
                            </td>. My data is many and only show 25 records for each page in gridview. And when I checked all rows in table, formcollection only get 25 records of page that is visible to me.

Comment: from these questions I want to know why some of your rows turn to hidden? for paging, or what?

Comment: Rows which have @ipitem.NetworkRanx.NetworkAddress were hidden because I want to use them for my filter row, but these rows don't show because i don't want to. Rows has button in comment because I don't need to use them so I commented. Rows which have @(ipitem.VPSs.VPSName) are showed or hidden belong to condition of my project.

Comment: I forgot, some rows that didn't have checkbox because of the condition of project does not allow it to be show. So that u don't need to care of these rows.

Comment: instead of `hidden="hidden"` please use `style="display:none;"` and see result in your context

Comment: Uhm sorry, I changed as you wanted, but not that i need. What i need to get all checked values include values in other pages of table, to remove it out of the table. Could you help me for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your `hidden="hidden"` to `style="display:none;"`.

And for you other pages, because you didnt use Ajax your data isn't exist in fact, so you can:

- use [Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16186083/making-a-simple-ajax-call-to-controller-in-asp-net-mvc) and hide your old rows and append new rows where exist
  all of your desired rows in your `html` however some of them be
  hidden.
- force your users to submit current page data and then switch pages.

Comment: So that are only ways, I will considered. Thank you so much!