# Ajax Call from Basic HTML page For a Footer In Rotativa

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can I make an Ajax Call to my Controller and Action method to get some data, from a HTML page instead of CSHTML page.
I have exactly the same content but instead of cshtml, I want to use a HTML page.

If Yes, please give me a sample code.

**EDIT**
The Actual Problem was different and I'm sorry for being unclear About it.

The Actual problem is I'm trying to generate a PDF using Rotativa.
And i wanted to add a footer to it and it contains some dynamic part.

```
            string header = System.IO.Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "Views/Home/header2.html");
        string footer = System.IO.Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "Views/Home/Footer.html");
        string customSwitches = string.Format("--header-html  \"{0}\" " +
                      //"--header-spacing \"0\" " +
                      "--page-offset 0 --header-right \"Page: [page] of [toPage]\" " +
                      "--footer-html \"{1}\" " +
                      "--footer-spacing \"10\" " +
                      //"--footer-font-size \"10\" " +
                      "--header-font-size \"10\" ", header, footer);
var pdfResult =  new ActionAsPdf("CreatePDF1", headerData)
        {
            FileName = "quotation.pdf",
            PageOrientation = Orientation.Portrait,
            PageSize = Size.A4,
            CustomSwitches = customSwitches
        };
```

The Following is my Footer.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
<link rel="icon" href="~/Assets/Images/logo.png" />
<link href="~/css/cupertino/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/css/cupertino/theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="~/js/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/jquery-ui-1.11.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id='divContent'></div>
    </body>

    </html>

    <script>
            $.ajax({
            url: "/Quotation/ReturnFooterData",
                type: 'get',
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                document.getElementById("divContent").innerHTML = data;
            },
                error: function (data) {
                document.getElementById("divContent").innerHTML = "error";

                }
            });
    </script>
```

That part data should be present in the PDF at the footer.
Here the ajax call what I make doesn't hit the action method.

This was my actual problem, and my apologies for not providing the exact information about the problem.

Comment: If you dont need razor syntax i think that you can do it

Comment: Yeah I dont need Razor syntax but i need an ajax call to be done to my action method.

Comment: You do know .cshtml page eventually renders to html in the end, Right?

Comment: @VishalA Ok, try it. You only need import jquery if you use it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a Simple Ajax call to controller in asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16186083/making-a-simple-ajax-call-to-controller-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
         $.ajax({
             contentType: "application/json",
             dataType: 'json',
             type: 'POST',
             url: '/Shop/FilterRinglet',
             data: data,
             success: function (result) {
                 //alert("success");
             }
        });
    });
</script>
```

inside your html.
Don´t forget to load jquery in your head section:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can do this [without jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery) too FYI