# ASP.NET MVC Input Model Binding without rendering the View again

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I use model binding in my application to get the Information from the view to my model class property.
I just want the entered data from my input form in the properties of my model class without rendering the view again. 
The binding works, but i dont know what i have to return in the Controller method.

**Model class(Events):**

`public string EventDay { get; set; }`

**Controller method:**

```
[HttpPost]
public void Search(Events model)
{
    var day = model.EventDay;
}
```

**Html input form:**

```
<form method="post" action="@Url.Action("Search","Book")">
    <div id="select-custom" class="box -custom">
        <label class="select-custom">
            <input class="input-custom" type="date" id="eventDay" name="eventDay" value="dd-mm-yyyy"/>
            <button type="submit" id="Search_reservation" class="button-custom display-none">Search</button>
        </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You should consider using Ajax calls from view, will this example help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16186083/making-a-simple-ajax-call-to-controller-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0):

By using an Ajax call you can send the data and also GET data.
and also you and set the data in DOM with referencing a page.

also, you can return JSON data using the JsonResult method of MVC.

Here I share some demo ajax call example here

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/using-ajax-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Seems ajax is what i am looking for. How would the JavaScript ajax function would look like? I am not really familiar with JavaScript.

Comment: $("#Search_reservation").click(function(){

var Events = {EventDay: $('#eventDay').val()};

$.ajax({  
         type: 'POST',
         url: '@Url.Action("Search")', 
  dataType: 'json',
  data: Events,  
         success: function (data) {  
          alert("Datsuccess callback")
 },
 error: function (ex) {  
   }  
});

}

Comment: you can upvote my answer so others and also see the answer if they have the same problem like yours

Comment: I did, but i have less then 15 reputation so it wont be displayed unfortunatly